# Why Apache Cassandra writes are so slow compared to MongoDB, Redis & MySql

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nosql

I recently started trying out some noSQL prototypes for a customer. They got a real-time application which does  lots of inserts, but less reads(Currently they are using MySql and would like to try out some noSQL solutions)

Over the weekend I tried Cassandra 2.0, MongoDB 2.4.9 and Redis to be compared to a normal Mysql 5.5 DB. All are running in my Windows i3 core 2.30 Ghz/8GB RAM laptop, so no high-end fancy machines.

The table structure is a simple one as below. Though it's the MySql DESC, Cassandra has the same structure, and in MongoDb it's stored as a JSON/BSON but got the same structure and indexes. It has got two indexes (oneway_id & twoway_id) for all the three db's.

**Structure (For all four db's)**

```
+--------------+---------------------+
| Field        | Type                |
+--------------+---------------------+
| tmstamp      | bigint(20) unsigned |
| field_1      | bigint(20) unsigned |
| field_2      | varchar(64)         |
| field_3      | varchar(64)         |
| field_4      | tinyint(3) unsigned |
| field_5      | bigint(20) unsigned |
| field_6      | varchar(25)         |
| field_7      | varchar(15)         |
| field_8      | varchar(15)         |
| field_9      | varchar(15)         |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

**DB/Environment details**

- MySql 5.6(64 bit) with mysql java connector 5.1.28
- Apache Cassandra 2.0 with datastax 2.0 Java drivers
- MongoDB 2.4.6 with mongo Java driver 2.12.0
- Redis 2.8.17 running on a linux machine
- Oracle Java 1.6(64 bit)
- Microsoft Windows 7(64 bit)
- Intel i3 core 2.30 Ghz processor
- 8GB RAM

Created a simple java test cases and these are the results I got (Though not consistently the same numbers but latencies are pretty much the same way):

**100,000 Records**

- MySql 1000,000 - 46 secs
- Cassandra      - 54 secs
- MongoDb        - 2  secs

**500,000 Records**

- MySql 1000,000 - 142 secs
- Cassandra      - 299 secs
- MongoDb        - 41  secs

**1,000,000 Records**

- MySql 1000,000 - 349 secs
- Cassandra      - 699 secs
- MongoDb        - 51 secs
- Redis          - 34  secs

> My question is why does Cassandra takes this long for such a small and
>   simple table inserts?

In Cassandra I tried both inline looped sql inserts & Batch inserts. The funny thing is batch inserts took more time. The document I followed for batch inserts is:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0

I don't want to use **asyncExecute**, because it doesn't gives me the exact insert time.

**Batch insert which I used is something like this(Which takes ages more than normal insert)**

```
PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("INSERT INTO some_table (val_1, val_2, val_3, val_4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();

//for loop start
batch.add(ps.bind(uid, mid1, title1, body1));
//for loop end

session.execute(batch);
```

**inline loop I used insert is something like this**

```
String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO some_table (val_1, val_2, val_3, val_4) VALUES (";

// for loop start

sqlInsert += uid+", "+", "+mid1+", "+title1+", "+body1+")";
session.execute(sqlInsert);

// for loop end
```

> **Now why is Cassandara slower than mysql** and more important -  **why is
>   MongoDB much much faster than Cassandra**? I seriously wish I am doing
>   something wrong?
>
> Is there a way I can insert JSON/BSON objects directly to Cassandra like MongoDB does? I
>   guess that might make it fast? Can some experts please help me on
>   this? If there are no answers I'll conclude that MongoDB is better than Cassandra!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code is using serial inserts. Each insert must wait for the previous to complete and return an acknowledgement before the next can begin. This is a bad way to benchmark any database that can handle multiple incoming connections. If you really don't want to use execute_async (the correct approach) you should write a multi-threaded stress program so that the inserts are not blocking (on the client side) and you are truly limited by the Cassandra node. Basically what you are seeing is the speed at which your client program can run rather than the capability of the database.

Blog Post of Interest points of interest:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-not-to-benchmark-cassandra

> There are only two principles to doing load generation right:
>
> Feed Cassandra enough work Generate the workload on separate machines
>   That’s it! But it’s frequently done wrong, **from the extreme case of a
>   single-threaded client running on the same laptop as Cassandra**, to
>   more subtle problems with the Python Global Interpreter Lock. It seems
>   that like binary search, it’s surprisingly difficult to build a good
>   load generator. If possible, avoid the temptation of rolling your own
>   and use something battle-tested.

Comment: Thanks. All good what you said. But that's the same way I am inserting the data into other databases (MySQL & MongoDB) and they are preforming far better than Cassandra. I will have read on that blogpost and revisit your answer. It looks quite interesting!

Comment: You aren't saturating any of the databases then and you need to adjust your test methodology. These databases are designed to handle multiple concurrent operations and any testing you are currently doing will be measuring your code more than the database.

An analogy would be trying to find out if Google or Yahoo could handle more load by running 100000 queries one at a time on each and seeing which completed the queries the fastest. What you are actually measuring is the interaction of your client with the internet and not the performance/throughput of Google or Yahoo's back-ends.

Comment: (measuring is the interaction..)How when it is running locally?Are you serious?I have used multi threaded inserts.But what I am reiterating is that MongoDB and Mysql performs better than Cassandra in terms of inserts.The time it took for 10000 Insert or say 100000 inserts(by X threads),the latency is much slower than than MySQL or MongoDB took.Thats my point here! BTW There isn't any tuning done one MongoDB,Mysql or Cassandra.And I have read so many articles that there isn't any performance tuning much to be done in terms of Inserts for Cassandra.

Comment: Commenting on Stackoverflow is a "PINTA" because of its character limit!!! I'll update the question with more information shortly with more findings.

Comment: I'll restate this because perhaps I wasn't clear.

You have two main problems.

Your driver program is competing for resources with the database itself.

The client is waiting on the OS to do a blocking operation in between inserts.

Comment: The fastest db in a single machine setup may not fastest db in a 1000 machine cluster.